# Multivariate probit analysis in stata

Tags: multivariate-analysis, stata, probit

I am using stata 12 as well ase stata 14.2
Here I am trying to run the multivariate probit model for my data set. But the command is not being read by stata. At the same time I am not being able to install the mvprobit package of stata.

I have checked number of youtube tutorials for this but haven't been able to run the model.